# How can I get hyperlinks on Google Slides to open in the same window?

Tags: hyperlink

I'm a kindergarten teacher trying to post a set of Google slides to support online learning.  I have a very modest understanding of HTML.  I want students to move to new slides by clicking hyperlinks, not by scrolling through like a presentation, so I made each slide (10-12 total) its own presentation.  It works, but every time you navigate from one to the other, it opens it in a new tab, which quickly turns into too many tabs.  I don't see a way to create links that open in the same window.
[campus](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1hmWy1ZseC2idm_PMc8KWaVMfPseH1p_VwXiQXM08qvI/pub?usp=sharing) (only READING link is set up at the moment)
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is code you could add to a SINGLE presentation slide that would open in a 'preview' tab which is a little different than present mode.  You would have to put all slides back into 1 slide presentation(file).  Replaced everything at the end including the word edit.
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1MV8HjEo4HAD9q9EwE8T77WbcwOxpUk48JogS9ffecLw/edit#slide=id.p

Then I would replace the above with--look at the end of the code.
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1MV8HjEo4HAD9q9EwE8T77WbcwOxpUk48JogS9ffecLw/preview?rm=minimal

Now clicking the links would keep the user on the same slide deck throughout all their clicks.  They can advance or go back depending on your links inside the presentation